# How does "sinking lid" work as a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

A "sinking lid" refers to a policy where employee numbers are reduced by not replacing employees that leave voluntarily (retire or resign).

Ref: https://www.lexico.com/definition/sinking_lid

How does this metaphor work?

Comment: I imagine @MichaelHarvey's answer is what you had in mind (if so, Michael, seems to me to deserve being an answer). If not, can you clarify what you mean by "how does it work"?

Comment: "Christchurch has a *so-called* “sinking lid” policy on pokie machines under which once a gambling venue closes, permission will not be given for another to reopen." [ref](https://agbrief.com/news/new-zealand/20/09/2021/new-zealand-facing-calls-for-tougher-gambling-to-protect-pacific-peoples/) I think it was probably meant to be self-explanatory as a name.

Comment: Google Books has examples that predate the earliest citation in the OED (1979) by a few years.

Comment: @AndyBonner This was the description that I was looking for, and it's makes perfect sense! I would certainly accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A local New Zealand term. Imagine a tank holding liquid. The level of the liquid represents the numbers of employees of the company. The tank might have a slight leak at the bottom, so the liquid level very slowly goes down. Or some might evaporate. That represents the slow loss of employees through resignation, death, retirement, etc. Now imagine a lid floating on the liquid. That prevents you removing liquid with a ladle, cup, or siphon. The lid represents the policy of not reducing the staff by redundancy or dismissal. As the water level sinks (goes down) so does the floating lid. The gradual loss is sometimes called 'natural wastage'.

The term 'sinking lid' is used in New Zealand more generally about policies where the level of something is allowed to reduce naturally, rather than by intervention. For example, the Wellington city council has a 'sinking lid' policy regarding licencing of poker type gambling machines in pubs and clubs. No new licences (British spelling) are granted. They call these devices 'pokie machines', I see in the [Stuff (NZ) web site](https://www.stuff.co.nz/the-press/news/126330323/city-council-sticks-with-sinking-lid-policy-on-pokie-machines)

A related term is 'cap'. If you put a cap on something (wages, bus fares, number of employees, whatever) you prevent that level or amount from rising above a selected limit.

Comment: I would suggest that a "cap" is a different concept from a "sinking lid" which is a new term to me but a very useful concept. Where a cap is in place on staff numbers, say, the maximum number is fixed but replacement up to that maximum is still practiced, in other words where numbers are capped the numbers do not reduce.

Comment: @BoldBen - I would regard a cap as a maximum which must not be exceeded. My team's headcount is capped at 25, and I have that number at the moment. If three people leave, I might ask HR to create one, two, or three vacancies, or, conceivably, none at all. My stationery budget is capped at £250 each month, but I don't have to spend that, and my home insurance contents cover caps claims at £2500 per individual item, but if my £500 TV is destroyed in an accident or stolen, I'll only be able to claim that sum.

Comment: Yes, a cap/fixed lid determines maximum possible contents, not actual contents.

Comment: The usual term for this in the UK is *attrition* or *natural attrition*.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. perhaps I should have said "numbers do not necessarily reduce"